# Why does TypeScript allow 1 + '1' = '11'? What's the design idea behind it?

Tags: typescript, type-coercion

If the idea is to add types to the system, why does it still allow the JavaScript style coercion? (Newbie here trying to understand the design thinking. Thanks!)

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript meaning that any functionality and behavior javascript has typescript will also have.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- Typescript is `Javascript` + `type`. So, what Javascript can do Typescript can also do that.
- Typescript code cannot be executed directly by web browsers. It will have to be transpiled to Javascript. And during the transpilation process, all type information will be removed. This point explains the above.
- Even strongly-typed programming languages, like C#, allow adding `number` to `string`.
- As C# allows adding `number` to `string`. Thus, there is no reason Typescript cannot allow that as they are both created by Microsoft.
- You can think of the type system of Typescript as a tool to help you create more robust code. For example, let's look at the below code:

  ```
  let a: number = 1;  
  let b: string = '1';  

  a = false;  

  console.log(a + b);
  ```

  Can you guess the output?
  Oh wait, does the code even compile/transpile?

  The output is `false1` and the Typescript code is still transpiled to Javascript code successfully. However, the transpiler will spit an error at your face saying: `Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'number'`. That's why I said `type` in Typescript is optional. It is only there to help making your code more robust.

Comment: I like how all this discussion actually is summarized by your third topic: "Even strongly-typed programming languages, like C#, allow adding number to string". That should be it, because this is not a JavaScript cohesion. Every major high-level language does concatenation of strings with numbers. I think OP meant to draw attention to other "weird stuffs" JavaScript (and TypeScript) does with strings and numbers and mistakenly said this.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I understand that TS is a superset of JS, but upon further thinking, why does it yell a type error for subtraction 1-'1' but not addition 1+'1', although JS allows the coercion in both cases?